# Why are my positions in different places when viewed in different browsers for the Protostar Joomla template?

Tags: joomla-3.x, protostar

I'm using Joomla 3.9.  Position 7 is to the right for the Edge browser, but on the bottom for Chrome.  How do I make sure it's on the right for all browsers?

Edge
[image: Image showing position 7 to the right of my featured article when viewed with Edge Browser]

Chrome
[image: Image showing position 7 under my featured article when viewed with Chrome Browser]

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Frank.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for feeback/support.

Comment: Make sure you have the same size for all window browsers